# Create wsdl for custom response header

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have to call a third party SOAP web service. I'm using c#, Visual Studio and WCF. The vendor can't provide me with a wsdl, so I am writing it myself, then adding a service reference using the wsdl I have created.

Here is a sample request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://sample.com/">
      <Username>...</Username>
      <Password>...</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetAttachment xmlns="http://sample.com/">
      <AttachmentID >4851888</AttachmentID>
    </Get>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is a sample response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <StatusType xmlns="http://sample.com/">
      <StatusNumber>0</StatusNumber>
      <Description>Success</Description>
    </StatusType>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAttachmentResponse xmlns="http://sample.com/">
      {
      ..json content
      }
    </GetAttachmentResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The wsdl I have created looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
                  xmlns:tns="http://sample.com/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
                  targetNamespace="http://sample.com/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
      <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sample.com/">

      <s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthHeader" />      
      <s:complexType name="AuthHeader">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>

      <s:element name="GetAttachment">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AttachmentID" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>

      <s:element name="StatusHeader" type="tns:StatusHeader" />
      <s:complexType name="StatusHeader">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="StatusNumber" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>

      <s:element name="GetAttachmentResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Attachment">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="mimetype" type="s:string" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="filename" type="s:string" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="content" type="s:base64Binary" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="s:string" />                  
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>

        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAttachment" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="tns:GetAttachmentResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentAuthenticationHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentStatusHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="StatusHeader" element="tns:StatusHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>


    <wsdl:portType name="AttachmentsSOAP">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAttachment">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="AttachmentsSOAP" type="tns:AttachmentsSOAP">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAttachment">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:GetAttachmentAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetAttachmentStatusHeader" part="StatusHeader" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="ApplyV1">
        <wsdl:port name="AttachmentsSOAP" binding="tns:AttachmentsSOAP">
            <soap:address location="https://api.sample.com/service"/>
        </wsdl:port>    
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I add the service reference, the proxy class that gets generated contains a GetAttachment function as I would expect.  The issue is that the response header is returned as the function return type, and the actual response (body) of the soap envelope is returned as an out parameter:

```
public AttachmentAPI.StatusHeader GetAttachment(AttachmentAPI.AuthHeader AuthHeader, AttachmentAPI.GetAttachment GetAttachment1, out AttachmentAPI.GetAttachmentResponse GetAttachmentResponse) {...}
```

I can call the GetAttachment function and it correctly makes a soap call.  The soap service returns a result and the result is deserialized into the GetAttachmentResponse object, but not the StatusHeader object.  Ideally the signature would look something like...

```
public AttachmentAPI.GetAttachmentResponse GetAttachment(AttachmentAPI.AuthHeader AuthHeader, AttachmentAPI.GetAttachment GetAttachment) {...}
```

...where AttachmentAPI.GetAttachmentResponse contains the response body and the custom response header. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, mostly, by putting the correct parts in the message, and referencing the message from both the portType and the binding.  This does function, although it still causes Visual Studio to generate a proxy class with what I would perceive as an undesirable function signature.  The header object is returned from the function and the object that the response body is deserialized into is returned as an out parameter:

```
public AttachmentAPI.StatusResponseHeaderType GetAttachment(AttachmentAPI.AuthRequestHeaderType AuthHeader, AttachmentAPI.GetAttachment GetAttachment1, out AttachmentAPI.GetAttachmentResponse GetAttachmentResponse) {...}
```

But at least it functions and I can retrieve the Status header and the actual body content.

Here is my modified wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://sample.com/"
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
                    targetNamespace="http://sample.com/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sample.com/">

      <s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthRequestHeaderType" />

      <s:complexType name="AuthRequestHeaderType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>

      <s:element name="StatusType" type="tns:StatusResponseHeaderType" />

      <s:complexType name="StatusResponseHeaderType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="StatusNumber" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>


      <s:element name="GetAttachment">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AttachmentID" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>

      <s:element name="GetAttachmentResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Attachment">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="mimetype" type="s:string" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="filename" type="s:string" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="content" type="s:base64Binary" />
                  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="s:string" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>

    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAttachment"   />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="StatusHeader" element="tns:StatusType" />
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="tns:GetAttachmentResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <!--<wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentAuthenticationRequestHeaderMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAttachmentStatusResponseHeaderMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="StatusHeader" element="tns:StatusHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>-->

  <!-- PortType defines the abstract interface of a web service. 
       Port type is implemented by the binding and service elements -->
  <wsdl:portType name="AttachmentsSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAttachment">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <!-- the binding specifies concrete implementation details and 
        essentially maps a portType to a set of protocols (HTTP and SOAP) 
        message styles (Document/RPC) and encodings (literal) -->
  <wsdl:binding name="AttachmentsSoap" type="tns:AttachmentsSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAttachment">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapIn" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal" />
        <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetAttachmentSoapOut" part="StatusHeader" use="literal" />
        <soap:body use="literal" parts="response"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="ApplyV1">
    <wsdl:port name="AttachmentsSoap" binding="tns:AttachmentsSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://api.sample.com/soap/apply/v1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are so tough, fortitude. I admire your ability to solve the issue. I do not know much about the WSDL, not to mention be able to write the WSDL manually. In my opinion, only we attach the username/password token can solve the authentication issue.
From the format of the client-side’s request, I think we can define the WCF client with the below binding.

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="mybinding">
     <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
     </textMessageEncoding>
     <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" >
     </security>
     <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
   </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

If the Server works over HTTP protocol, please replace the `httpstransport` with `httpTransport`.
Then we can construct the client request.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://abcd:8008/service");
            BindingElementCollection bec = new BindingElementCollection();
            bec.Add(SecurityBindingElement.
                CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
            //for http server with a certificate.
            //bec.Add(SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameForCertificateBindingElement());
            bec.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());
            bec.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bec);
            ChannelFactory<IService1> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService1 service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var result=service.myoperation()
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: No this doesn't solve my issue.  It's not anything to do with the username/password - that is in the REQUEST header, and works fine.  I'm talking about the RESPONSE header.

Comment: @Jeremy  .  Sorry, I didn't fully understand your question. I would like to ask, by changing the client SOAP request, we can change the data format of the third-party service response?